# English equivalent of "令牌"?

Tags: translation

I have "commanding badge", but it doesn't sound too well. It there a specific name for the actual "令牌"?

EDIT: In the context of history/novels

Comment: Give some context please.

Comment: f you mean the history of Taoism then see baike.baidu.com/view/544102.htm. Or do you mean modern military history? Or do you mean some on-line community devoted to historical novels, like a stackexchange, that gives badges?

Answer (score 1):

This '令牌敲响‘ is confusing. Possibly, the author was thinking of, or referring to a metal plate similar to a cymbal, maybe hanging on a string, which could be hit with a stick to produce a sound. The old guy hit it to drive out the demons. Sure would drive me crazy! 'Out out damn spot!'

I would translate '令牌‘ as 'badge of authority', or maybe here 'cymbal of authority'.

Comment: when you say "symbol of authority", do you mean in the context of a physical image (a symbol that shows someone's authority), or as in a person who has authority (a person who is a symbol of authority)? 
Just wanted to check, as it's somewhat unclear which you mean without elaboration

Comment: haha, cymbal is not symbol. cymbal = 钹，镲，铙

Comment: My mistake! I assumed it was a typo, but it wasn't haha. Thanks for clearing that up for me >_>

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts, like Computer Science, it can mean 'token', e.g. 令牌环 is 'token ring'.

Comment: Ehh, meant in history and stuff (or novels)

Comment: OK, just be sure to specify your context next time.

Comment: Btw, try using an image search, and check what it looks like. It actually does look like a badge or a pendant without the string attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if an equivalent existed in western military history.

A general would issue a 令牌 when a subordinate needs to act with the general's authority. For example, you'd need a 令牌 from a city's garrison commander to have the gates opened for you at night.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems to be more of an amulet of sorts used by Daoists in rituals.

So you might try something like 'mystical/magical pendant/amulet'

Answer (score 0):

I'd translate it as insignia, or token of command.  The modern use of a 令牌 is in one time passwords as a translation for "security/autentication token."